# Is there any command like code . for eclipse?

Tags: java, linux, eclipse

I'm starting on linux and I was curious to see how visual studio code can be run from the console with the command "code ." but I didn't find anything similar for eclipse.

Comment: Maybe you can find an answer to your question here: https://www.testingdocs.com/questions/how-to-launch-eclipse-from-terminal-in-linux/#:~:text=To%20run%20Eclipse%20from%20anywhere,directory%20to%20PATH%20environment%20variable.&text=Append%20eclipse%20directory%20to%20the%20PATH.&text=Save%20the%20file.,anywhere%20in%20the%20Terminal%20windows. Alternatively you can define an alias to run eclipse with another keyword.

Comment: You can run Eclipse from the command line if you include it in the path.  But it would load the default workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, yes, via the `--launcher.openFile` command line option according to the [reference help](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html?cp=2_1_6_0), however bugs [579618](https://bugs.eclipse.org/579618) and [564340](https://bugs.eclipse.org/564340) are still open, so actually no. High quality patches to fix this functionality, or make something better, would probably go over well.